How to display entries of specific author on author page
Hello I need help to find a way to display posts[entries] by an author on his author page . Thanks for help
I tried exp: tags to select entries with author_id but that didn't work.The page is showing all posts.
When I add field to channel named author_name and select that in exp:channel tags it shows nothing
Expression engine version:7
Expecting
How to get author_name from segment_2 as author_id. And use the author_name to get entries(posts) of that specific author.
Thanks in advance

In the simplest of cases you would use this:
{exp:channel:entries author_id="{segment_2}" dynamic="no"}
{title}
{/exp:channel:entries}


You can also use the authors username if the URL matches, such as example.com/authors/johndoe
{exp:channel:entries username="{segment_2}" dynamic="no"}
{title}
{/exp:channel:entries}

